# How to search for a pattern and print two lines before it for all matches found

Tags: shell-script, centos, pattern-matching

I have a file with information about different protein entries. Each entry includes: details of the sequences (top line), number of times any alphabet is found in the sequence (second line) and the amino acid alphabet in the third line.

Example given below:

```
sp|Q5N386|PETN_SYNP6 Cytochrome b6-f complex subunit 8 OS=Synechococcus sp. (strain ATCC 27144 / PCC 6301 / SAUG 1402/1) OX=269084 GN=petN PE=3 SV=1
A=4 D=1 E=1 F=4 G=5 I=1 L=5 M=2 N=1 R=1 S=2 T=2 V=3 W=2
Amino acid alphabet = 14

sp|Q20EX4|PETG_OLTVI Cytochrome b6-f complex subunit 5 OS=Oltmannsiellopsis viridis OX=51324 GN=petG PE=3 SV=1
A=2 D=1 E=1 F=1 G=4 I=1 L=7 M=1 P=2 Q=1 R=2 S=1 T=2 V=6 Y=2
Amino acid alphabet = 15

sp|P81612|MYTA_MYTED Mytilin-A OS=Mytilus edulis OX=6550 PE=1 SV=1
A=5 C=8 F=2 G=4 K=4 R=6 S=3 W=1 Y=1
Amino acid alphabet = 9
```

What command shall I use such that when I want to find all entries that have `Amino acid alphabet = 9`,  it should also print the two preceding lines into a different file? Such the output file should look like:

```
sp|P81612|MYTA_MYTED Mytilin-A OS=Mytilus edulis OX=6550 PE=1 SV=1
A=5 C=8 F=2 G=4 K=4 R=6 S=3 W=1 Y=1
Amino acid alphabet = 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU `grep` has a `-B` (`--before-context`) option for this:

```
grep -F -B2 -x 'Amino acid alphabet = 9' file
```

If your `grep` does not have this option, you can use `awk`:

```
awk -v RS= '/Amino acid alphabet = 9$/' file
```

(I'm assuming your records are separated by a blank line, as in your example)

Comment: yes, all the entries are separated by a blank line. How do I print the results to a different file? I ran this command on the bash terminal: fgrep -B2 -x 'Amino acid alphabet = 9' input_filename. I'm assuming I need to give the output filename somewhere? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Davi I just notice now that you use CentOS which has GNU grep; you should then prefer the `fgrep` command. You can store the output by appending `> file.out` to any of the two commands.

Comment: Don't use `fgrep` (or `egrep` or `rgrep`, they've all been deprecated for many years now). Use `grep -F` instead.  Or, in this case, `grep -F -B2 ...`

Comment: @davi if this answer worked for you, you should click on the big grey tick mark (so that it turns green) to accept it.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @cas You are right, thanks. Answer fixed. Old habits die hard....

Comment: @cas thanks for pointing that out. Done!

Comment: I have a follow up question on that. So, is there a way to extract the entries that have a subset of the alphabets? So, for example, doesn't matter if there are any other alphabets or not, if there is an entry that has A=*, D=*, and S=* in any order, I want to extract them out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Davi You probably want to `grep '[ADS]='` (possibly with `-A1 -B1`) but I'm not sure I understand your need. If this is not what you want, please open a new question.